# Обратиться к изображению из папки drawable по имени файла

Tags: android, изображения, android-drawable

Собственно, вопрос в названии. Необходимо присвоить картинку элементу imageview, зная только имя файла картинки. Видел, что это можно сделать буквально одной строкой, но потерял этот ответ

Comment: `imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_name);` - не оно?

Comment: @woesss нет-нет, я знаю только image_name, по нему мне и надо обратиться к изображению

Answer (score 4, accepted):

вот, кому интересно, нашел

```
int imageID = view.getResources().getIdentifier(image_name, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
iv.setImageResource(imageID);
```